# jQuery slide show, issue with fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i'm having issues with a small slideshow.

```
 // define array of image paths (src) 
 var backgroundImage = [
   { src: 'assets/bg/1.jpg' }, 
   { src: 'assets/bg/2.jpg' }, 
   { src: 'assets/bg/3.jpg' }, 
   { src: 'assets/bg/4.jpg' }, 
   { src: 'assets/bg/5.jpg' }];


 $(document).ready(

     function() {

         // index to select item in array
         var i = 0;

         // use the jQuery function ($) to select the <img> by id
         var img = $('#back-img');

         // set the initial src value 
         img.attr("src", backgroundImage[i].src);

         // advance to next image 
         i++;

         // setInterval takes to parameters, a callback and an interval 
         window.setInterval(function() {

                 // reset the index to 0 if past the end
                 if (i >= backgroundImage.length) {
                     i = 0;
                 }

                 // fade out the old image and fade in the new one 
                 img.attr("src").fadeOut(900, function() {
                     alert("ok")
                 });

                 img.attr("src", backgroundImage[i].src).fadeIn('900');

                 // advance to next image
                 ++i;
             },

             // set the image time to 7000ms
             7000
         )
     }
 );
```

the script doesn't work. it load the first image but doesnt swap to the other ones. I guess something is wrong with my fadeOut function cause if i replace it with a hide() func, it works...

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S4SmM/459/

Comment: try replacing img.attr("src").fadeOut with img.fadeOut

Answer (score 1):

You had a syntax error in `.fadeOut()` it needed to be called directly on the img not the `.attr`

```
img.fadeOut('900', function() {alert("ok")});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S4SmM/476/

You may want to also consider putting the image changing code inside the callback where `alert("ok");` is called.

Here is an example of the smoother animation in the callback:

```
// fade out the old image and fade in the new one 
img.fadeOut('900', function() {
    img.attr("src", backgroundImage[i].src).fadeIn('900'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S4SmM/485/

Comment: i fixed it but it does a weird flashing effect, i just want to fade out smootly to the next image